# Why use different gas?

Tags: solidity, gas, gas-estimate

I have this contract with this functions, why each use different gas amount?

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract Foo {
  //transaction cost: 21471 gas 
  //execution cost: 199 gas
  //total cost: 21670 gas
  function withoutNewS() external {
    uint256[3] storage data;
  }
  //transaction cost: 21427 gas 
  //execution cost: 155 gas
  //total cost: 21582 gas
  function withoutNew() external {
    uint256[3] data;
  }
  //transaction cost: 21533 gas 
  //execution cost: 261 gas
  //total cost: 21794 gas
  function withoutNewM() external {
    uint256[3] memory data;
  }
  //transaction cost: 21607 gas 
  //execution cost: 335 gas
  //total cost: 21942 gas
  function withNewM() external {
    uint256[] memory data = new uint256;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are leveraging different memory locations of the EVM (memory and storage have very different meanings and implications, as you can see [here](https://medium.com/coinmonks/ethereum-solidity-memory-vs-storage-which-to-use-in-local-functions-72b593c3703a) for example). These different elements have different purposes and you should always strive for the least gas-consuming one which is still fit for your purpose, as EVM rewards carefully optimised code with less costs.